# Go - operator overloading

Tags: go

I have started to study Go and I am trying to understand what happens below:

```go
time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond) // Works
time.Sleep("1000ms") // Doesn't work
```

If you print to the console `time.Milliseconds` you can see `1ms`. So I think that I can simply call that method with the value `"1000ms"`, but I get an error. Next I searched for operator overloading in Go, but it doesn't support it. I understand that `time.Sleep` gets the `time.Milliseconds` data type, but how does Go allow it if it doesn't support overloading operators like `*`?

Comment: `time.Sleep` takes a `time.Duration`. See the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep

Comment: If you print `time.Duration` to console, you'll get output of `(time.Duration) String() string` method result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Sleep()` accept a `Duration type` which is `int64`. So you can't pass string type object as an argument without typecasting it.

You got the output `1ms` because of this method

```
(time.Duration) String() string
```

Comment: I gave you an upvote for trying to be helpful as you answered at the same time, no idea why people would downvote your answer, and then answer in the comments when the guidelines say - 'Avoid answering questions in comments'.

Comment: @KennyGrant this answer was previously incomplete and incorrect. My downvote is now withdrawn. Additionally, answering poor questions in comments is preferred to providing proper answers to poor questions.